# Is there any way to update the values of a list using python list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

for example: `primes = [0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1] #here primes is a list`

now I want to update the values of primes. The iteration which correctly works is below.

```
for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):    
 for j in range(i,n,i):
  if(primes[j] == -1):
   primes[j] = i
```

here n = 10, i=2. so basically iteration starts from i and goes to 10 with increment of i.
for example if we start from j=i=2 then after first iteration we will increment 2 and find if primes[j] == -1. this will result in following after first iteration.

primes[0,0,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2].

after second iteration when i becomes 3, now the multiples of 3 will be updated if primes[j] == -1 and we will get following after second iteration.

primes[0,0,2,3,2,-1,2,-1,2,3,2]

I want to know a method for inner loop which can be written in below form. (Below form is called python list comprehension. I want to update the values using python list comprehension or using slicing method.)

```
primes[i : n: i] = [i for j in range(i,n,i) if primes[j] == -1]
```

it is giving me error as below:

ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to extended slice of size 3

Comment: A list comprehension is used *to create a new list*, always, that is what it does. Of course, you can use slice-assignment to update a list with another list, i.e `somelist[some_slice] = some_list` but you have to know the size ahead of time. Why don't you just stick with the code you have that works?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your valuable comment. I want to know list updation using list comprehension or slice-assignment because for some cases it is faster than using loops (as I have done above using two for loops). So just to optimize the code and improve the efficiency I want to update it with slice-assignment method/ list comprehension method.

Comment: It is very important to understand, *list comprehensions are only marginally faster than the equivalent for-loop*. List comprehensions are for *readability*, not performance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga will this difference be marginal for computing large data say around a million? Actually, I am working on that so I have no idea about this difference.

Comment: Yes, it is always marginal. A list comprehension *uses a python for loop*. And note, a million iterations is not very large. However, *slice assignment* is appreciably faster than updating the list one element at a time, so you may see an improvement there.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for this knowledge update in my python dictionary :)

Answer (score 1):

Also not sure why you would want to do this, but that is not upto me:

```
for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
    primes[i : n: i] = [i if primes[j]==-1 else primes[j] for j in range(i,n,i) ]
```

Comment: I want to know list updation using list comprehension or slice-assignment because for some cases it is faster than using loops (as I have done above using two for loops). So just to optimize the code and improve the efficiency I want to update it with slice-assignment method/ list comprehension method.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, by filtering in your list comprehension, you end up with fewer elements to assign than the size of the target subscript.  You need to match the number of positions in the subscript even if that means re-assigning the current value.

here is how you could do it:

```
primes[i : n: i] = [ [primes[j],i][primes[j]==-1] for j in range(i,n,i) ]
```

or

```
primes[i : n: i] = ( i if p<0 else p for p in primes[i:n:i] )
```

Note that, to be more efficient, your loop should skip values that are not primes because those will never update any of the entries in primes (given that they will have been assigned a value by previous primes):

```
primes = [0,0]+[-1]*(n-1)
for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
    if primes[i]<0:
       primes[i::i] = (i if p<0 else p for p in primes[i::i])
```

This will also result in each position in `primes` containing the smallest prime factor of the corresponding number (up to √n) but it will do it faster.

Using -1 as a convention for unseen factors may not be ideal.  You could, for example, initialize the list with each number at its own position.  That way, the positions that you do not cover by stopping at the square root of `n` will contain the corresponding number which also happens to be its own smallest prime divisor:

```
primes = list(range(n+1))
for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
    if primes[i]<i: continue
    primes[i*i::i] = (min(i,p) for p in primes[i*i::i])
```